Is every finite lattice isomorphic to a union-closed family of sets containing $\emptyset$?
If a family of sets $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^E$ is union-closed and contains $\emptyset$, then $\mathcal{F}$ forms a lattice under the set-inclusion order. To see this, note that unions give the join operation, and that for $X, Y \in \mathcal{F}$, if we let $$Z = \bigcup \{ W | W \in \mathcal{F}\text{ and }W \le X, Y \},$$ then $Z \in \mathcal{F}$ is the meet of $X, Y$.
Now, I'd like to know whether a converse of this is true. Namely, if I am given a finite lattice $L$, can I find a union-closed (and containing $\emptyset$) family $\mathcal{F}$ over some set $E$, such that $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}$?
Background and discussion:
I'm trying to characterize some class of lattices, and I have proven that they are always isomorphic to such an $\mathcal{F}$. I strongly suspect that they in fact are characterized by much stronger properties. But, I would like to know whether being isomorphic to such an $\mathcal{F}$ places any restrictions on the class of lattices whatsoever.
The question could be viewed as a generalization of Birkhoff's representation theorem, and also as a variant of this question: Is every finite poset a subset of a finite complemented distributive lattice?.
However, the straightforward approach of that question, and generalizing Birkhoff-type ideas of join and meet irreducible, seems insufficient. Or, perhaps the result is false, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample $L$ or establish some property satisfies by this type of $\mathcal{F}$ but not by general lattices.
Thanks ahead of time!

yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

@mathworker21 care to elaborate?

Given $x\in L$, let $S_x={y\in L,:,y\not\geq x}$.

@RichardStanley wow! Very simple - thank you. If you'd like to copy your comment into an answer (just to 'check the box' etc) that would be excellent

Stanley's observation  is also presumably in  Birkhoff's Lattice Theory (1940).

Thanks @SamHopkins and @GeraldEdgar! Not sure about Birkhoff's book, but it looks like [Birkhoff & Frink 1947] "Representations of lattices by sets" contains the result with a slightly more involved construction. I found that paper via the references in the [Thomas & Williams] arxiv link - looks like a useful way of thinking of things which I'll keep picking through - thanks!

For some reason SamHopkins's comments are gone. He recommended the references https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-203-00/S0002-9947-1975-0360386-3/ and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.10123.pdf which indeed look relevant for the general context (even if not giving the specific answer)

@ClayThomas: sorry, I decided these comments actually made sense as an answer to the related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450680. By the way now you can see that all Stanley did for the answer for this question is to take complements for the answer to that one (changing an intersection-closed family to a union-closed family).

I am converting my comment into an answer at the request of the proposer. Given $x\in L$, let $S_x=\{y\in L\, :\, y\not\geq x\}$.

Finite complete lattices and sup-preserving functions form a very nice category C; the category of models for the theory with one nullary operation (say 0) and a commutative, associative, idempotent binary operation (say +) having 0 as unit. This theory is commutative, so C has homs and tensors, making it a monoidal closed category with unit object (say I) the free model on one generator. Moreover, Hom( - , I) is a duality. Hom(X,I) is just the poset X turned upside down, and Hom(f,I) is the right adjoint of the homomorphism f if we think of the objects of C as categories and the maps of C  as colimit-preserving functors. If P(S) denotes the Boolean algebra of subsets of S, as an object of C, then P(S) is the free model on S. Every model X is a quotient of some P(S), and hence, by duality, a subobject of some P(S'), which answers the question in the affirmative. A convenient set of generators for a model X is the set of those elements x for which the subset { a | 0 <= a <= x} is linearly ordered. So X embeds as a poset in P(S') where S' = { x | { x <= a <= 1} is linearly ordered} where 1 is the top element of X. X is distributive if for any x, y and z with z <= x+y
there exist a and b with a <= x, b <= y and z = a+b (i.e. X has pullbacks of sup-diagrams).
All this pother is saying no more than Richard Stanley's more compact comment. A question: are semisimplicial resolutions of objects of C by free
objects finite? In other words, given a finite sup-lattice X is there an essentially finite semi-simplicial sup-lattice, with free members, whose
sup-lattice of connected components is isomorphic to X? My guess is yes.
